# Where to ask non-programmatic questions about Office tools (and other non-programmer tools)

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

On which SE site should I ask questions related to the Office or OpenOffice etc Suite? If non exists, I'd vote for creating a special SE site.

Comment: What **kind** of questions? How to script those tools? Or just how to get a specific task done without scripting? Your question is exceedingly vague.

Comment: Non-programmatic use of Office tools. How to achieve a certain functionality only through use of the program GUI and/or already written plug-ins. Or if impossible/too complex for OP, a suggestion of how to script it/achieve programmatically (without actually going into details about how to do it)

Comment: That sounds like a [Super User](http://superuser.com) type of question.

Comment: Changed question would appreciate undoing the -1 for which there is now IMO no justification.
Also : no need for "your question is this or that" + answering as answer and not comment seems to be better practice.
Delete this comment afterwards please.
Thanks for your help

Comment: No, that's not how it works. Your question needed clarification as it was too vague. There are no points on Meta, so there is no need to be sensitive about the score of your post.

Comment: I agree I'm just saying that your questions were the real useful part which helped me correct myself, they sufficed. As for the score it's not so much about my rep but about the usefulness of the question to the community and it's ranking there :)

Comment: Sorry about the -1s. I just gave a +1. It's exactly what I was asking myself a minute ago. SE is spaming question sites like crazy. An **that** creates the necessity to ask questions like this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to guess without seeing a sample question but I would suggest [Super User](http://superuser.com) would be a good fit for such questions.

As you hover-over the [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel),[word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) questions on SO you will see those are expected to involve programming. So if your questions are not about programming(automating) but about using UI and built-in ribbon "tools" I think [Super User](http://superuser.com) is a more suitable site for such questions.

Comment: I have this impression as well, however the overall goal of SU seems to be system-related questions, hence my feeling of "we are lacking an SE site for this type of question"
However, as a noob, I will not take on myself to create an SE site, and if question on SU are tagged correctly it should be possible to move them (he said, dreaming).

Comment: @Kharski - SU is definitely the place.

Comment: @Kharski please see the [SuperUser's help centre page](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) for more info. I think Office tools qualify for the computer software category.